# How do I compare values in two columns and then mark true/false in a third?

Tags: vba, find, excel-2010, lookup

Can someone please help me create a macro that will search two columns on a worksheet for a list of conditions and mark true/false on the third column. (office 2010)

e.g.

Column A would have the following values: 1111,1,2,3,3,4,...
Column B would have the following values: O,A,Y,A,S,3Y,...

If the following matching conditions are met, the column C would mark as TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

```
A       B
1111 =  O
0    =  Y
1    =  A
2    =  S
3    =  3YRY
4    =  Q
6    =  B
12   =  M
13   =  V
360  =  D
```

CONDITION RULES:

```
IF column A = 1111 AND column B = O 
OR 
IF column A = 0 AND column B = Y 
OR 
IF column A = 1 AND column B = A 
OR 
IF column A = 2 AND column B = S 
OR 
IF column A = 3 AND column B = 3YR 
OR 
IF column A = 4 AND column B = Q 
OR 
IF column A = 6 AND column B = B 
OR 
IF column A = 12 AND column B = M 
OR 
IF column A = 13 AND column B = V 
OR 
IF column A = 360 AND column B = D 
THEN COLUMN C = "TRUE" ELSE "FALSE"
```

Comment: I've tried formulas but I couldn't get the nested vlookup to work with index. I'm searching online to see if I can find a similar example to make this work. I'm not very good with vba so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want one "true" or "false" in the entire column, or do you want one per row, according to that row's comparative outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match more closely what you're wanting to accomplish, any questions about what's happening here let me know.

```
Option Base 1

Sub testCriteria()

'arrays for criteria r, r2.  Array for T/F r3
Dim r, r2, r3(10, 1)

'iterators for loop and variable for output column
Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long

    'column for output of t/f
    c = 3

    'location of criteria cells h1 through i10
    r = [h1:i10]

    'location of comparison
    r2 = [a1:b10]

    'loop through rows of rows to check (r2) and compare with all rows from criteria (r)
    For i = LBound(r2) To UBound(r2)
        For j = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
            If CStr(r(j, 1)) = CStr(r2(i, 1)) _
            And CStr(r(j, 2)) = CStr(r2(i, 2)) _
            Then r3(i, 1) = "TRUE"
        Next j
        If Not r3(i, 1) Then r3(i, 1) = "FALSE"
    Next i

    'reusing iterators for array limits
    i = LBound(r3): j = UBound(r3)

    'loading t/f array into api
    Range(Cells(i, c), Cells(j, c)) = r3

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look through to see if I can make sense of it..

Edit: I added the necessary conditions to the question for a easier view.

Comment: Hey Clyde, I used the filter option and managed to do this without any coding. Thank you, hopefully someone else can find this helpful. :)

Comment: oh excellent, glad to "try" to be of assistance. Take Care :D